# MySQL does not list sql file imported tables on a Mac with MySQL Workbench

Tags: macos, mysql-workbench, zend-server

I am unable to solve this.

I have installed Zend Server on a Mac. I also installed MySQL Workbench. I have imported a SQL Schema from a .sql file to MySQL database via command line. The schema importation was OK, but MySQL Workbench did not show the tables schema.

I also tried to import et via MySQL Workbench with the same result. I tried to change the way to communicate with MySQL from socket to tcp ip and also get the same result.

I test the exact same thing on an Ubuntu installation of Zend Server with MySQL Workbench and all went right.

Does anyone have get this problem solved on a Mac with Zend Sever and MySQL Workbench ?

Any help will be apreiacte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Zend Server 6.0.0 from my Mac with with the unistaller script :
sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/uninstall.sh

and then installed the updated Zend Server version 6.0.1. After that all works well and now MySQL Workbench is able to fetch tables.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to assign rights to see the new data to the user used to connect in MySQL Worbkench. For this log in with a root user account (or any other that is allowed to change privileges) and do the assignment in the admin section. You can check at the same time if your root user can see the new tables (which he should, since he's the root user).

Comment: I am using root user to make the connection. The root user can see the tables via comand line interface but with MySQL Workbench the messages Fetching tables is all what I get. Conducting a searh I have found this http://www.nebev.net/blog/?p=442. Does anyone works with Zend Server 6.x with MySQL Workbench on a Mac an solved the problem ?